# iCloud files unrecoverable after transfer to external disk?

Tags: icloud, finder, hard-drive, external-disk

I had a 90GB directory on iCloud in my Documents folder, of which maybe 85GB was offloaded to cloud with only 5GB on disk. I transferred the whole directory to my 4TB external drive, and it seemed to finish properly. All files were on the external drive and all sizes were correct (individual files had the correct sizes in Finder, and the whole directory was 90GB). So I removed the folder from Documents and emptied Trash to free up all that space.

I then noticed, when I went to work in the directory, that while all files showed up in Finder, only a handful showed up when typing `ls` in Terminal. I then interrogated the files under "Get Info" in Finder, and saw that while some files were multiple GB, only 4 kb were "on disk."

This seems really bad. Is the data recoverable?

Thanks!

Comment: How did you do file transfer?

Comment: You have my sympathies, but I think what you copied was mainly a folder full of aliases. Check iCloud online & see if it has a trash folder you can recover from.  Apple often give you 30 days to change your mind. Otherwise… did you have a backup?

Comment: @mmmmmm I did it via Cmd-C and Cmd-V in the window. Waited about an hour so that I thought maybe anything that needed to be redownloaded would have made it.

Comment: @Tetsujin I was thinking the same thing. I can try to check iCloud online. Unfortunately no backup :( That's what this transfer to the drive was supposed to be. I didn't have enough space to redownload everything and then transfer. How else would have been a smart way to do this?

Comment: I think re-download then copy would be the only way. It's not something I've ever done. I avoid iCloud for file storage precisely because of this "it's not a backup solution, it's a sync solution" issue which catches many people out.

Comment: If you go to icloud drive on the web there is an option so see recently deleted files - that might be enough in this case.

Comment: Unfortunately recently deleted has nothing :( Guess I'll have to find a very creative solution